# Setting value on ViewController class

Tags: ios, estimote

I'm new to iOS development, but I'm trying to modify the [example app](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK/tree/master/Examples/IndoorLocation%20SwiftExample) provided by Estimote (I'm working with their Indoor Positioning SDK). In the example, there is a ViewController class called MenuViewController that contains a function called -loadLocationFromJSON(). Now, inside this function they create a new instance of a ViewController called locationViewController which gets pushed to the navigationController.  So far, that all works fine and the location file builds correctly and is displayed on screen.

Now what I want to do is to create a switch which is located in the MenuViewController class which can toggle an attribute on the LocationViewController.  The locationViewController has a property of its indoorLocationView called rotateOnPositionUpdate which you can set to true or false.  Right before I push the locationViewController, I'd like to set that property according to the switch in my MenuViewController class.  Here's what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func loadLocationFromJSON() {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("location", ofType: "json")
    let content = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) as String
    let location = ESTLocationBuilder.parseFromJSON(content)
    var locationViewController:LocationViewController = LocationViewController(nibName: "LocationViewController", bundle: nil)
    locationViewController.location = location
    // the following line is where the code fails
    locationViewController.indoorLocationView.rotateOnPositionUpdate = false

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(locationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

As you no doubt noticed, right now I'm just trying to set the property to false (and not even worry about the state of the switch)... but this fails when I try to build it.  The debugger returns an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  I don't entirely know what this means and I don't know why I can't set the property of that locationViewController class.  Can someone provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewControllers do not construct their views until they are first requested. Usually, this is during the `pushViewController` step, but it doesn't have to be.

Additionally, It's likely that they have declared `indoorLocationView` as optional because it is a view and they construct it when the rest of the view is loaded. You'll need to either check for `nil` explicitly or use the `?` operator to avoid crashes when accessing properties that might be `nil`.

```
locationViewController.indoorLocationView?.rotateOnPositionUpdate = false
```

When `indoorLocationView` is `nil`, this line will not crash, but it will also have no effect. You should either change the implementation of `LocationViewController` to accept this parameter directly and then pass it on to its `indoorLocationView` or set it after you've called `pushViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Adding the "?" operator did keep it from crashing... but as you said... the line of code doesn't really have any effect. It seems like having the LocationViewController accept this value from the MenuViewController would be the way to go... but I'm not sure how to do it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add a property to your `LocationViewController` class and then set `indoorLocationView`'s property from that value inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Right... I understand that (and have been able to do that just fine).  But, what I want is to have a value outside of the LocationViewController.  So, there would be a stored bool value (ideally coming from a switch) in MenuViewController that would somehow set the indoorLocationView's property from within the LocationViewController.  Does that make sense?  So, either the MenuViewController has to pass a value to the LocationViewController when it gets pushed... or the LocationViewController has to go and get the value from the MenuViewController after it's loaded.  Not sure how to do either.

Comment: If you've created a property on `LocationViewController`, just set it right after you set the `location` property value: `locationViewController.rotateOnPositionUpdate = false`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `indoorLocationView` is not loaded in memory yet at this time. So you need to make a property to store the Bool value.
`var canRotateOnPositionUpdate` in `LocationViewController` and set `rotateOnPositionUpdate` property after the `indoorLocationView` loaded. I think it will be loaded in some point at `viewWillAppear()`. just like the following:

```
    @IBAction func loadLocationFromJSON() {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("location", ofType: "json")
    let content = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) as String
    let location = ESTLocationBuilder.parseFromJSON(content)
    var locationViewController:LocationViewController = LocationViewController(nibName: "LocationViewController", bundle: nil)
    locationViewController.location = location
    // the following line is where the code fails
    locationViewController.indoorLocationView.canRotateOnPositionUpdate = false

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(locationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

then

```
        func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.indoorLocationView.drawLocation(self.location)
        self.manager.startIndoorLocation(self.location)
        self.indoorLocationView.rotateOnPositionUpdate = self.canRotateOnPositionUpdate
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: Ok.  I assume you mean the ViewDidLoad() function inside the LocationViewController.  So, assuming that, then I somehow need to access the Bool value in the parent ViewController (the MenuViewController).  So, how do I do that?  I'm sorry if that's a really beginner question... but like I said, I'm new to this.

Comment: I'm still not sure this solves the problem.  If I'm creating a variable in the LocationViewController called canRotateOnPositionUpdate and then updating the property inside the viewWillAppear() function... then everything is still inside the LocationViewController... What I want is to somehow control the property inside the LocationViewControl from the MenuViewController.  So, somehow I need to pass a variable from the MenuViewController to the LocationViewController... but having trouble doing that.

Comment: You can override the setter of canRotateOnPositionUpdate in the LocationViewController to update the value from MenuViewController

Comment: Kindly up-vote the answer or mark it as answered if you find it helpful to help other developers to get the best answer. Thanks